# Combining UsedRanges for all Worksheets in an Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, windows

I'd like to iterate through all the Worksheets in an Excel Workbook and get the combined contents into a single Excel.Range.

```
xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText(fDialog.FileName, DataType: Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, TextQualifier: Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter: true, Comma: true);

xlSheets = xlApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets;

foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in xlSheets)
{        
    range += sheet.UsedRange;  //How do I concatenate these UsedRanges so range = the total of all the Worksheets?                        
}
```

I know the += doesn't work I just included it to signify the concatenation I'm looking to achieve.

Thanks

Comment: `range1 = xlApp.Union(range1,range2)`

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was able to create some logic that seems to be getting the correct Sheet data before each Union but it's throwing this exception...Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC. I think it may be because there are some NULLS in sheet.UsedRange. I assumed UsedRange would only return the used cells. Any ideas on how to ignore the NULLS? Thanks again.

Comment: Nulls (assuming you mean empty cells) shouldn't be a problem. UsedRange isn't always totally reliable: if you have tabular data then using something like `CurrentRegion` can work better. You do need to check you're not using Union with one or more empty arguments, and you can't use Union when you're starting with an empty range variable (in that case you use a regular assignment)

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm not calling xlApp.Union until the second pass through my loop and I confirmed neither range is empty via the debugger. I'm just not sure why it's throwing that exception.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas.  If you update your question with the current code then someone else may have a suggestion.